# How I can get keycloak realm certs using spring boot application in docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker-compose, oauth-2.0, keycloak

It's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
  version: "3.7"
    
    volumes:
      pgdata:
        driver: local
    
    
    services:
      database:
        container_name: postgres-realityquest-db
        image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
          - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
          - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
        volumes:
          - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    
      app:
        image: reality-quest
        container_name: app
        depends_on: [database, keycloak]
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
      
      keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak
        container_name: local-keycloak
        ports:
          - "8024:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./imports:/tmp/import
        environment:
          - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
          - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
        command:
          - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
          - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
          - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/import"
```

It's my application.properties file:

```
 server.port=8081
    #POSTGRESSQL DATASOURCE CONFIGURATION
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-realityquest-db:5432/test
    #spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=root
    
    #HIBERNATE CONFIGURATION
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
    
    #LIQUIBASE CONFIGURATION
    spring.liquibase.change-log=db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
    
    #SECURITY CONFIGURATION
    spring.security.filter.order=10
    
    #RESOURCE SERVER CONFIGURATION
    spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8024/auth/realms/custom-oauth2-server/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

When container is running I can successfully get JWT token from keycloak using POSTMAN, but when I send a request to API a get error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8024/auth/realms/custom-oauth2-server/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

All works fine when I do it without docker.
I will be grateful for the help

Answer (score 0):

First check if the url of jwks_uri is correct to found it got to this url:

```
 http://keycloakhost:keycloakport/auth/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

In json result you will see the jwks_uri

Comment: "jwks_uri": http://localhost:8024/auth/realms/custom-oauth2-server/protocol/openid-connect/certs - my jwks_uri in openid-configuration, eventually I get exception when try to send request with Auth token to my app in container

Comment: what is the result of opening the jwks_uri

Answer (score 0):

**Keycloak Version - 22.0.4 + Kubernetes Environment**

I had this error (on Spring Boot Application Console) after I put my containers from local environment to a kubernetes (minikube) environment.

The difference: The Spring Boot Application connects to the Keycloak within the cluster network. The Spring Boot Security uses

> `security: oauth2: resourceserver: jwt: jwk-set-uri: $(my_jwk-set-uri_variable)`

to connect to the keycloak. $(my_jwk-set-uri_variable) needs to be a cluster address.

This would be either the name of the service or the ip of the service.
(For Kubernetes: **kubectl get service** shows the Cluster-IP adresses.)

Format :

jwk-set-uri:

> http://**<ip-or-service-name>**:**<keycloak-port**>/realms/**<your-realm>**/protocol/openid-connect/certs

---

**Related problem:**

> `security: oauth2: resourceserver: jwt: issuer-uri: $(my_issuer-uri_variable)`

has to be the **iss** variable within your token. The token can be decoded via: https://jwt.io/.